# Google Spreadsheet - Only use negative cells in another cells forumla

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I would like to only show which amount each person owes. Green numbers are values they have paid, grey shows they were not present during that week and red is what they are oweing from that game week.

Currently the only forumla I can think of is:

```
=sum(B2:E2)
```

However I have tried to use:

IF((B2:E2)<=0) but I have no idea how to include this in the forumla.

Is it possible to only use negative numbers in a forumla?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gary's Student's formulae work in Google Sheets.

You could also use

```
=sumif(B2:E2,ʺ>0ʺ)
```

and

```
=sumif(B2:E2,ʺ<0ʺ)
```

Comment: Oh perfect mate :) amazing haha :D

Answer (score 2):

In *Excel* this will sum the positives in a range:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:E2)*(B2:E2>0))
```

and use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:E2)*(B2:E2<0))
```

to sum the negatives!